# bash: put list files into a variable and but size of array is 1

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am listing the files in a directory and looping through them okay, BUT I need to know how many there are too. ${#dirlist[@]} is always 1, but for loop works?

```
#!/bin/bash
prefix="xxx"; # as example

len=${#prefix}; # string length
dirlist=`ls ${prefix}*.text`;
qty=${#dirlist[@]};  # sizeof array is always 1
for filelist in $dirlist
do
    substring="${filelist:$len:-5}";
    echo "${substring}/${qty}";
done
```

I have files xxx001.text upto xxx013.text
but all I get is 001/1  002/1  003/1

Comment: use `dirlist=($(ls ${prefix}*.text))` to create a array

Comment: Cheers Kev I had to change the loop to for filelist in ${dirlist[@]}

Comment: @kev You were first in and gave me what I needed, can you submit an answer please

Comment: as David Ongaro commented in one of the answers, use `dirlist=(${prefix}*.text)` to create an array. It will handle filenames with spaces successfully.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This:

```
dirlist=`ls ${prefix}*.text`
```

doesn't make an array. It only makes a string with space separated file names.

You have to do

```
dirlist=(`ls ${prefix}*.text`)
```

to make it an array.

Then `$dirlist` will reference only the first element, so you have to use

```
${dirlist[*]}
```

to reference all of them in the loop.

Comment: Use `"${dirlist[@]}"` instead of `${dirlist[*]}` to guard against files whose names contain whitespaces.

Comment: And please don't use `ls`! `dirlist=(${prefix}*.text)` is simpler and less error prone.

Comment: @DavidOngaro Why is that?

Comment: In the best case the `ls` is just redundant, since the shell is already doing the expansion of `${prefix}*.text` which `ls` will see as parameters. In the worst case `ls` will output additional information (like ANSI color codes, filtetype suffixes) depending on the environment, so the script will break. I guess this habit from using `ls` in front of a glob expression comes from a dos/windows mindset where `dir` was doing the expansion, but not the shell.

Comment: And even putting performance aspects aside, it's just messier and unnecessary to create subshells and call external programs, if the shell can do the work.

Answer (score 5):

Declare an array of files:

```
arr=(~/myDir/*)
```

Iterate through the array using a counter:

```
for ((i=0; i < ${#arr[@]}; i++)); do

  # [do something to each element of array]

  echo "${arr[$i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not creating an array unless you surround it with `(` `)`:

```
dirlist=(`ls ${prefix}*.text`)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dir=/tmp
file_count=`ls -B "$dir" | wc -l`
echo File count: $file_count
```

Answer (score 0):

The *array* syntax in `bash` is simple, using parentheses `(` and `)`:

```
# string
var=name

# NOT array of 3 elements
# delimiter is space ' ' not ,
arr=(one,two,three) 
echo ${#arr[@]}
1

# with space
arr=(one two three)
# or ' ',
arr=(one, two, three)
echo ${#arr[@]}
3

# brace expansion works as well
# 10 elements
arr=({0..9})
echo ${#arr[@]}
10

# advanced one
curly_flags=(--{ftp,ssl,dns,http,email,fc,fmp,fr,fl,dc,domain,help});
echo ${curly_flags[@]}
--ftp --ssl --dns --http --email --fc --fmp --fr --fl --dc --domain --help
echo ${#curly_flags[@]}
12
```

if you want to run a command and store the output

```
# a string of output
arr=$(ls)
echo ${#arr[@]}
1

# wrapping with parentheses
arr=($(ls))
echo ${#arr[@]}
256
```

A more advanced / handy way is by using **built-in** bash commands `mapfile` or `readarray` and **process substitution**. here is is an example of using `mapfile`:

```
# read the output of ls, save it in the array name: my_arr
# -t    Remove a trailing DELIM from each line read (default newline)
mapfile -t my_arr < <(ls)
echo ${#my_arr[@]}
256
```