# Copying defined Lines to another files in Linux Bash

Tags: linux, filter, grep, export

I have a problem with Script, which i run on a Debian based distribution:
I want to copy each whole Line which contains "Hello World" into a new text file.
Now, i'm doing it with this Script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
string1=$(grep "Hello World" log.txt)
if [ "$string1" != "" ]; then
    echo $string1 >> output.txt
fi
truncate --size 0 log.txt
```

But there's one Problem:
I'm running this script scheduled each hour.
If in one hour are 10 "Hello World" written in the log.txt, i will get in the output.txt all line's which matched "Hello World" on one simple line. It's very confusing to read this.

How can i export each whole line which contains "Hello World" to the output.txt in seperated lines?

(The last line with truncate is only that i don't get written empty lines)

Comment: Sounds like a problem that could be solved by reviewing the commandline options of `grep`...

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but i i've read many times, can't find this setting. i know, if you search for something on the cli, the output is multiline. But when you use it in a Script and put it to a variable, it's single line. i know variables are normally single line. but is there a solution to put each match in one string of an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a statement such as `var=$(grep "pattern" file)` in a script causes the variable to contain the entire set of statement results separated by spaces.  To produce a file containing each result on a separate line, write something like

```
var=$(grep "pattern" file)
for v in "$var"
do
  echo $v >> $outfile
done
```

However, this will have issues with any patterns/lines which contain spaces, so it might be better to do something like the following:

```
var=($(grep "pattern" file)) # creates an array
for v in "${var[@]}" # guards against whitespace issues
do
  echo $v >> $outfile
done
```

If you only need statistics, you might also consider using `var=$(grep -c "pattern" file)`.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224535/bash-put-list-files-into-a-variable-and-but-size-of-array-is-1).

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any particular reason you decided to loop through the results in the script instead of executing something like `grep "pattern" file >> log.txt`?